# Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile /app.jar when built using azure devops pipelines

Tags: spring-boot, docker, gradle, azure-devops

The following Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:13-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
VOLUME /var/data
VOLUME /var/log
EXPOSE 8080
ARG JAR_FILE
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

for a spring-boot application builds and runs fine on a local docker. However when I run the build through azure devops it builds fine, but when I try to run it, I get the following error:

```
Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile /app.jar
```

Could it be that Azure Devops can't inject the ARG JARFILE arguments the way locally built from intellij/gradle?

Comment: Are you sure that the JAR is being built correctly?

Comment: I fixed it, it could not find the jars files